# Sublime Text: Disable single quote auto-completion in Lisp

Tags: sublime-text-3

I am using Sublime Text to program in Lisp. I have automatic completion for parentheses, brackets and quotes enabled. In Lisp, it is quite common to use a single quote (`'`), e.g. when creating an instance of a class.

```
(make-instance 'my-class)
```

In this case, no auto-completion of the single quote is necessary.

How can I turn the auto-completion of the single quote off, but only for Lisp source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a keybinding to your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "'"},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.lisp" }
    ]
},
```

This will overwrite the default behavior and insert `'` only in lisp files.